# Angular Directive Under Test Not Being Created

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test my Angular directive. I already have some unit tests on another directive that are working just fine. Here's the content of the `typeahead-input.directive.ts` file:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[hsaTypeaheadInput]',
})
export class TypeaheadInputDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  private destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  @Input() typeaheadDebounceTime: number = 300;
  @Output() valueChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(private searchInput: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.setupTypeaheadObservable();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
  }

  setupTypeaheadObservable() {
    fromEvent(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        map((ev: KeyboardEvent) => {
          if (ev && ev.key === 'Escape') {
            this.searchInput.nativeElement.blur();
          }
          return ev;
        }),
        filter(
          (ev: KeyboardEvent) =>
            ev.key !== TypeaheadKeys.ENTER &&
            ev.key !== TypeaheadKeys.UP &&
            ev.key !== TypeaheadKeys.DOWN &&
            ev.key !== TypeaheadKeys.ESC,
        ),
        debounceTime(this.typeaheadDebounceTime),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(() => this.valueChanged.emit(this.searchInput.nativeElement.value)),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

Essentially, an observable is created to output a new value after a `debounceTime`. The observable works when I test it out in Stackblitz. But Now I'm trying to write tests for it, and that's where I'm running into issues. As for the test setup, I created a `TestHostComponent`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-host',
  template: `
    <input hsaTypeaheadInput type="text" />
  `,
})
class TestHostComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(TypeaheadInputDirective) typeaheadInputDirective: TypeaheadInputDirective;
  public typeaheadDebounceTime: number = 300;
  valueChanged(newValue: string) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.typeaheadInputDirective);
  }
}
```

The `AfterViewInit` code on this test component is just to see if the `typeaheadInputDirective` is available. It's not, it's undefined.

Here is the rest of the test set up:

```
describe('TypeaheadInputDirective', () => {
  let component: TestHostComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestHostComponent, TypeaheadResultDirective],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create a component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

That first test actually does work; the `component` variable is truthy. But the directive is never instantiated or run. I'm not sure why though. Is there anything here that I'm doing incorrectly that's keeping the directive from being created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When configuring the test module, you have the following declarations:

```
declarations: [TestHostComponent, TypeaheadResultDirective]
```

However, your component is using the TypeaheadInputDirective, which is not declared in your test module.

You should update the declarations to include the directive:

```
declarations: [TestHostComponent, TypeaheadResultDirective, TypeaheadInputDirective]
```

Comment: Ugh, I checked that, but apparently not close enough. I can't believe I've been this confused for this long haha Thanks for taking a look for me.

Comment: No worries! :-)